# What is the difference between Run-instances and create-instances in aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I know run instances is to create the ec2-instance in aws-cli but what is create instances?? and also what is stack-id and layer-ids. I google it but didn't found any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at 2 AWS services here. In AWS CLI, `run-instances`refer to creating EC2 server.

`create-instance` is used in AWS OpsWorks, to create an instance in OpsWorks stack. In OpsWorks there are stacks and Layers. A stack is a collection of layers and layer represents a stack component, such as a load balancer or a set of application servers. `stack-id` refers to the Stack's ID to identify the desired OpsWorks stack and `layer-id` refers to a particular layer in the given stack.

I'll add the CLI documentation below since you didn't find it.

EC2 - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

OpsWorks - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/create-instance.html